# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Woo! I feel a bit bad though, with my rep being so low in comparison. We need more questions, time to advertise more!

Comment: Don't feel bad about it, you're putting a ton of effort into the meta. All I've done is answer a bunch of questions with answers that people seem to like. :)

Comment: Yeah, reputation is nice but isn't a determinate. As long as you take the communities opinions into consideration when appropriate, I'm glad to have anyone else do the grunt work of moderation! I think a "grats" might be appropriate.